# Unmarshalling JSON with variable-length data and slices of other JSON objects

Tags: json, go, nested

I have a question on how Go handles unmarhsalling complex/nested JSON as it appears I have to create the entire data structure in structs prior to unmarshalling.

I am working with a JSON file that follows this format (it is the NVD database, reference here if it is helpful https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/data-feeds):

```html
"CVE_data_type" : "CVE",
  "CVE_data_format" : "MITRE",
  "CVE_data_version" : "4.0",
  "CVE_data_numberOfCVEs" : "1085",
  "CVE_data_timestamp" : "2021-02-24T17:00Z",
  "CVE_Items" : [ {
"cve" : {
  "data_type" : "CVE",
  "data_format" : "MITRE",
  "data_version" : "4.0",
  "CVE_data_meta" : {
    "ID" : "CVE-2011-0762",
    "ASSIGNER" : "cve@mitre.org"
  },
  "problemtype" : {
    "problemtype_data" : [ {
      "description" : [ {
        "lang" : "en",
        "value" : "CWE-399"
      } ]
    } ]
  },
  "references" : {
    "reference_data" : [ {
      "url" : "ftp://vsftpd.beasts.org/users/cevans/untar/vsftpd-2.3.4/Changelog",
      "name" : "ftp://vsftpd.beasts.org/users/cevans/untar/vsftpd-2.3.4/Changelog",
      "refsource" : "CONFIRM",
      "tags" : [ ]
    }, {
      "url" : "http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=622741",
      "name" : "http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=622741",
      "refsource" : "CONFIRM",
      "tags" : [ ]
    }, {
      "url" : "http://cxib.net/stuff/vspoc232.c",
      "name" : "http://cxib.net/stuff/vspoc232.c",
      "refsource" : "MISC",
      "tags" : [ "Exploit" ]
    }, {
      "url" : "http://jvn.jp/en/jp/JVN37417423/index.html",
      "name" : "JVN#37417423",
      "refsource" : "JVN",
      "tags" : [ ]
    }, {
      "url" : "http://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/package-announce/2011-March/055881.html",
      "name" : "FEDORA-2011-2615",
      "refsource" : "FEDORA",
      "tags" : [ ]
    }, {
      "url" : "http://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/package-announce/2011-March/055882.html",
      "name" : "FEDORA-2011-2590",
      "refsource" : "FEDORA",
      "tags" : [ ]
    }, {
      "url" : "http://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/package-announce/2011-March/055957.html",
      "name" : "FEDORA-2011-2567",
      "refsource" : "FEDORA",
      "tags" : [ ]
    }, {
      "url" : "http://lists.opensuse.org/opensuse-security-announce/2011-05/msg00005.html",
      "name" : "SUSE-SR:2011:009",
      "refsource" : "SUSE",
      "tags" : [ ]
    }, {
      "url" : "http://marc.info/?l=bugtraq&m=133226187115472&w=2",
      "name" : "HPSBMU02752",
      "refsource" : "HP",
      "tags" : [ ]
    }, {
      "url" : "http://securityreason.com/achievement_securityalert/95",
      "name" : "20110301 vsftpd 2.3.2 remote denial-of-service",
      "refsource" : "SREASONRES",
      "tags" : [ "Exploit" ]
    }, {
      "url" : "http://securityreason.com/securityalert/8109",
      "name" : "8109",
      "refsource" : "SREASON",
      "tags" : [ ]
    }, {
      "url" : "http://www.debian.org/security/2011/dsa-2305",
      "name" : "DSA-2305",
      "refsource" : "DEBIAN",
      "tags" : [ ]
    }, {
      "url" : "http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/16270",
      "name" : "16270",
      "refsource" : "EXPLOIT-DB",
      "tags" : [ ]
    }, {
      "url" : "http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/590604",
      "name" : "VU#590604",
      "refsource" : "CERT-VN",
      "tags" : [ "US Government Resource" ]
    }, {
      "url" : "http://www.mandriva.com/security/advisories?name=MDVSA-2011:049",
      "name" : "MDVSA-2011:049",
      "refsource" : "MANDRIVA",
      "tags" : [ ]
    }, {
      "url" : "http://www.redhat.com/support/errata/RHSA-2011-0337.html",
      "name" : "RHSA-2011:0337",
      "refsource" : "REDHAT",
      "tags" : [ ]
    }, {
      "url" : "http://www.securityfocus.com/archive/1/516748/100/0/threaded",
      "name" : "20110301 vsftpd 2.3.2 remote denial-of-service",
      "refsource" : "BUGTRAQ",
      "tags" : [ ]
    }, {
      "url" : "http://www.securityfocus.com/bid/46617",
      "name" : "46617",
      "refsource" : "BID",
      "tags" : [ "Exploit" ]
    }, {
      "url" : "http://www.securitytracker.com/id?1025186",
      "name" : "1025186",
      "refsource" : "SECTRACK",
      "tags" : [ ]
    }, {
      "url" : "http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/USN-1098-1",
      "name" : "USN-1098-1",
      "refsource" : "UBUNTU",
      "tags" : [ ]
    }, {
      "url" : "http://www.vupen.com/english/advisories/2011/0547",
      "name" : "ADV-2011-0547",
      "refsource" : "VUPEN",
      "tags" : [ ]
    }, {
      "url" : "http://www.vupen.com/english/advisories/2011/0639",
      "name" : "ADV-2011-0639",
      "refsource" : "VUPEN",
      "tags" : [ ]
    }, {
      "url" : "http://www.vupen.com/english/advisories/2011/0668",
      "name" : "ADV-2011-0668",
      "refsource" : "VUPEN",
      "tags" : [ ]
    }, {
      "url" : "http://www.vupen.com/english/advisories/2011/0713",
      "name" : "ADV-2011-0713",
      "refsource" : "VUPEN",
      "tags" : [ ]
    }, {
      "url" : "https://exchange.xforce.ibmcloud.com/vulnerabilities/65873",
      "name" : "vsftpd-vsffilenamepassesfilter-dos(65873)",
      "refsource" : "XF",
      "tags" : [ ]
    } ]
  },
  "description" : {
    "description_data" : [ {
      "lang" : "en",
      "value" : "The vsf_filename_passes_filter function in ls.c in vsftpd before 2.3.3 allows remote authenticated users to cause a denial of service (CPU consumption and process slot exhaustion) via crafted glob expressions in STAT commands in multiple FTP sessions, a different vulnerability than CVE-2010-2632."
    } ]
  }
},
"configurations" : {
  "CVE_data_version" : "4.0",
  "nodes" : [ {
    "operator" : "OR",
    "cpe_match" : [ {
      "vulnerable" : true,
      "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:beasts:vsftpd:0.0.1:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
    }, {
      "vulnerable" : true,
      "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:beasts:vsftpd:0.0.2:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
    }, {
      "vulnerable" : true,
      "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:beasts:vsftpd:0.0.3:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
    }, {
      "vulnerable" : true,
      "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:beasts:vsftpd:0.0.4:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
    }, {
      "vulnerable" : true,
      "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:beasts:vsftpd:0.0.5:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
    }, {
      "vulnerable" : true,
      "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:beasts:vsftpd:0.0.6:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
    }, {
      "vulnerable" : true,
      "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:beasts:vsftpd:0.0.7:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
    }, {
      "vulnerable" : true,
      "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:beasts:vsftpd:0.0.8:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
    }, {
      "vulnerable" : true,
      "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:beasts:vsftpd:0.0.9:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
    }, {
      "vulnerable" : true,
      "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:beasts:vsftpd:0.0.10:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
    }, {
      "vulnerable" : true,
      "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:beasts:vsftpd:0.0.11:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
    }, {
      "vulnerable" : true,
      "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:beasts:vsftpd:0.0.12:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
    }, {
      "vulnerable" : true,
      "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:beasts:vsftpd:0.0.13:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
    }, {
      "vulnerable" : true,
      "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:beasts:vsftpd:0.0.14:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
    }, {
      "vulnerable" : true,
      "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:beasts:vsftpd:0.0.15:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
    }, {
      "vulnerable" : true,
      "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:beasts:vsftpd:0.9.0:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
    }, {
      "vulnerable" : true,
      "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:beasts:vsftpd:0.9.1:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
    }, {
      "vulnerable" : true,
      "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:beasts:vsftpd:0.9.2:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
    }, {
      "vulnerable" : true,
      "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:beasts:vsftpd:0.9.3:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
    }, {
      "vulnerable" : true,
      "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:beasts:vsftpd:1.0.0:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
    }, {
      "vulnerable" : true,
      "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:beasts:vsftpd:1.0.1:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
    }, {
      "vulnerable" : true,
      "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:beasts:vsftpd:1.1.0:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
    }, {
      "vulnerable" : true,
      "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:beasts:vsftpd:1.1.1:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
    }, {
      "vulnerable" : true,
      "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:beasts:vsftpd:1.1.2:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
    }, {
      "vulnerable" : true,
      "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:beasts:vsftpd:1.1.3:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
    }, {
      "vulnerable" : true,
      "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:beasts:vsftpd:1.2.0:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
    }, {
      "vulnerable" : true,
      "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:beasts:vsftpd:1.2.1:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
    }, {
      "vulnerable" : true,
      "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:beasts:vsftpd:1.2.2:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
    }, {
      "vulnerable" : true,
      "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:beasts:vsftpd:2.0.0:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
    }, {
      "vulnerable" : true,
      "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:beasts:vsftpd:2.0.1:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
    }, {
      "vulnerable" : true,
      "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:beasts:vsftpd:2.0.2:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
    }, {
      "vulnerable" : true,
      "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:beasts:vsftpd:2.0.3:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
    }, {
      "vulnerable" : true,
      "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:beasts:vsftpd:2.0.4:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
    }, {
      "vulnerable" : true,
      "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:beasts:vsftpd:2.0.5:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
    }, {
      "vulnerable" : true,
      "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:beasts:vsftpd:2.0.6:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
    }, {
      "vulnerable" : true,
      "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:beasts:vsftpd:2.0.7:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
    }, {
      "vulnerable" : true,
      "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:beasts:vsftpd:2.1.0:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
    }, {
      "vulnerable" : true,
      "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:beasts:vsftpd:2.1.1:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
    }, {
      "vulnerable" : true,
      "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:beasts:vsftpd:2.1.2:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
    }, {
      "vulnerable" : true,
      "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:beasts:vsftpd:2.2.0:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
    }, {
      "vulnerable" : true,
      "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:beasts:vsftpd:2.2.1:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
    }, {
      "vulnerable" : true,
      "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:beasts:vsftpd:2.2.2:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
    }, {
      "vulnerable" : true,
      "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:beasts:vsftpd:2.3.0:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
    }, {
      "vulnerable" : true,
      "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:beasts:vsftpd:2.3.1:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
    }, {
      "vulnerable" : true,
      "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:beasts:vsftpd:*:*:*:*:*:*:*:*",
      "versionEndIncluding" : "2.3.2"
    } ]
  } ]
},
"impact" : {
  "baseMetricV2" : {
    "cvssV2" : {
      "version" : "2.0",
      "vectorString" : "AV:N/AC:L/Au:S/C:N/I:N/A:P",
      "accessVector" : "NETWORK",
      "accessComplexity" : "LOW",
      "authentication" : "SINGLE",
      "confidentialityImpact" : "NONE",
      "integrityImpact" : "NONE",
      "availabilityImpact" : "PARTIAL",
      "baseScore" : 4.0
    },
    "severity" : "MEDIUM",
    "exploitabilityScore" : 8.0,
    "impactScore" : 2.9,
    "obtainAllPrivilege" : false,
    "obtainUserPrivilege" : false,
    "obtainOtherPrivilege" : false,
    "userInteractionRequired" : false
  }
},
"publishedDate" : "2011-03-02T20:00Z",
"lastModifiedDate" : "2021-02-19T05:15Z"
  }, {
"cve" : {
  "data_type" : "CVE",
  "data_format" : "MITRE",
  "data_version" : "4.0",
  "CVE_data_meta" : {
    "ID" : "CVE-2011-4362",
    "ASSIGNER" : "cve@mitre.org"
  },
  "problemtype" : {
    "problemtype_data" : [ {
      "description" : [ {
        "lang" : "en",
        "value" : "CWE-189"
      } ]
    } ]
  },
  "references" : {
    "reference_data" : [ {
      "url" : "http://archives.neohapsis.com/archives/bugtraq/2011-12/0167.html",
      "name" : "20111224 Lighttpd Proof of Concept code for CVE-2011-4362",
      "refsource" : "BUGTRAQ",
      "tags" : [ "Broken Link" ]
    }, {
      "url" : "http://blog.pi3.com.pl/?p=277",
      "name" : "http://blog.pi3.com.pl/?p=277",
      "refsource" : "MISC",
      "tags" : [ "Third Party Advisory" ]
    }, {
      "url" : "http://download.lighttpd.net/lighttpd/security/lighttpd_sa_2011_01.txt",
      "name" : "http://download.lighttpd.net/lighttpd/security/lighttpd_sa_2011_01.txt",
      "refsource" : "CONFIRM",
      "tags" : [ "Vendor Advisory" ]
    }, {
      "url" : "http://jvn.jp/en/jp/JVN37417423/index.html",
      "name" : "JVN#37417423",
      "refsource" : "JVN",
      "tags" : [ ]
    }, {
      "url" : "http://redmine.lighttpd.net/issues/2370",
      "name" : "http://redmine.lighttpd.net/issues/2370",
      "refsource" : "CONFIRM",
      "tags" : [ "Vendor Advisory" ]
    }, {
      "url" : "http://secunia.com/advisories/47260",
      "name" : "47260",
      "refsource" : "SECUNIA",
      "tags" : [ "Third Party Advisory" ]
    }, {
      "url" : "http://www.debian.org/security/2011/dsa-2368",
      "name" : "DSA-2368",
      "refsource" : "DEBIAN",
      "tags" : [ "Third Party Advisory" ]
    }, {
      "url" : "http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/18295",
      "name" : "18295",
      "refsource" : "EXPLOIT-DB",
      "tags" : [ "Third Party Advisory", "VDB Entry" ]
    }, {
      "url" : "http://www.openwall.com/lists/oss-security/2011/11/29/13",
      "name" : "[oss-security] 20111129 Re: CVE Request: lighttpd/mod_auth out-of-bounds read due to signedness error",
      "refsource" : "MLIST",
      "tags" : [ "Mailing List", "Third Party Advisory" ]
    }, {
      "url" : "http://www.openwall.com/lists/oss-security/2011/11/29/8",
      "name" : "[oss-security] 20111129 CVE Request: lighttpd/mod_auth out-of-bounds read due to signedness error",
      "refsource" : "MLIST",
      "tags" : [ "Mailing List", "Third Party Advisory" ]
    }, {
      "url" : "http://www.securitytracker.com/id?1026359",
      "name" : "1026359",
      "refsource" : "SECTRACK",
      "tags" : [ "Third Party Advisory", "VDB Entry" ]
    }, {
      "url" : "https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=758624",
      "name" : "https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=758624",
      "refsource" : "CONFIRM",
      "tags" : [ "Issue Tracking", "Third Party Advisory" ]
    }, {
      "url" : "https://exchange.xforce.ibmcloud.com/vulnerabilities/71536",
      "name" : "lighttpd-base64-dos(71536)",
      "refsource" : "XF",
      "tags" : [ "Third Party Advisory", "VDB Entry" ]
    } ]
  },
  "description" : {
    "description_data" : [ {
      "lang" : "en",
      "value" : "Integer signedness error in the base64_decode function in the HTTP authentication functionality (http_auth.c) in lighttpd 1.4 before 1.4.30 and 1.5 before SVN revision 2806 allows remote attackers to cause a denial of service (segmentation fault) via crafted base64 input that triggers an out-of-bounds read with a negative index."
    } ]
  }
},
"configurations" : {
  "CVE_data_version" : "4.0",
  "nodes" : [ {
    "operator" : "OR",
    "cpe_match" : [ {
      "vulnerable" : true,
      "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:lighttpd:lighttpd:*:*:*:*:*:*:*:*",
      "versionStartIncluding" : "1.4.1",
      "versionEndExcluding" : "1.4.30"
    }, {
      "vulnerable" : true,
      "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:lighttpd:lighttpd:1.5.0:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
    } ]
  }, {
    "operator" : "OR",
    "cpe_match" : [ {
      "vulnerable" : true,
      "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:debian:debian_linux:5.0:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
    }, {
      "vulnerable" : true,
      "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:debian:debian_linux:6.0:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
    }, {
      "vulnerable" : true,
      "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:debian:debian_linux:7.0:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
    } ]
  } ]
},
"impact" : {
  "baseMetricV2" : {
    "cvssV2" : {
      "version" : "2.0",
      "vectorString" : "AV:N/AC:L/Au:N/C:N/I:N/A:P",
      "accessVector" : "NETWORK",
      "accessComplexity" : "LOW",
      "authentication" : "NONE",
      "confidentialityImpact" : "NONE",
      "integrityImpact" : "NONE",
      "availabilityImpact" : "PARTIAL",
      "baseScore" : 5.0
    },
    "severity" : "MEDIUM",
    "exploitabilityScore" : 10.0,
    "impactScore" : 2.9,
    "obtainAllPrivilege" : false,
    "obtainUserPrivilege" : false,
    "obtainOtherPrivilege" : false,
    "userInteractionRequired" : false
  }
},
"publishedDate" : "2011-12-24T19:55Z",
"lastModifiedDate" : "2021-02-19T05:15Z"
  },
```

As you can see, there is a lot of data here, and I am struggling to get this unmarshalled into something that I can work with. The first few fields are straightforward, so I have begun creating a struct as such:

```
type NvdData struct {
CveDataType string `json:"CVE_data_type"`
CveDataFormat string `json:"CVE_data_format"`
CveDataVersion string `json:"CVE_data_version"`
CveDataNumberCves string `json:"CVE_data_numberOfCVEs"`
```

}

Where I am confused is when we get to the "CVE_Items" field which contains a list/slice of "CVE" objects that then all have their own various fields, some of which are lists, some which aren't.

My question is, how do I construct my `NvdData` struct to handle this? Do I need to create an additional struct, `CVE` , which has all of the various fields associated with each CVE entry, and include that data structure as part of my `NvdData` definition? Something like:

```
type NvdData struct {
    CveDataType string `json:"CVE_data_type"`
    CveDataFormat string `json:"CVE_data_format"`
    CveDataVersion string `json:"CVE_data_version"`
    CveDataNumberCves string `json:"CVE_data_numberOfCVEs"`
    CveItems []Cve{} `json:"CVE_Items`
}

type Cve struct {
    DataType string `json:"data_type"`
    DataFormat string `json:"data_format"`
    ...
}
```

If that makes sense? And then for any subsequent data structures that are lists/slices, I would have to describe those as a struct as well and the `type` for that json field would be a slice of that type?

One last one-off question I have as well is, if there are fields that I don't care about can I drop them from the type definition and they will be ignored by the Unmarshalling process, or do I need to describe them as well and just ignore them when I iterate through the data?

Comment: You should define a struct for each JSON object, and a slice for each JSON array. You can omit the fields you are not interested in.

Comment: Thanks for the quick comment, @BurakSerdar. So just to clarify, I was correct above in that (for example) the ```CveItems``` would be a slice of my custom-defined ```Cve``` struct? And then the case would be the same for the other fields in the source data.

Comment: Correct, each JSON object would be a separate struct type.

Comment: Just use https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/

Comment: @Volker Ohhhh man, how did I not know that was a thing after I literally just finished defining all the structs. Saved for future reference.....

Answer (score 2):

I saw that there is a schema online for this: https://csrc.nist.gov/schema/nvd/feed/1.1/nvd_cve_feed_json_1.1.schema

Which has this, which defines a CVE item (it references other definitions in the same file). You could in theory use this to create the various structs. There is an attempt to auto generate the structs here: https://adrianhesketh.com/2016/07/19/json-schema-to-go-struct-generator-roundup/

```json
"def_cve_item": {
            "description": "Defines a vulnerability in the NVD data feed.",
            "properties": {
                "cve": {"$ref": "CVE_JSON_4.0_min_1.1.schema"},
                "configurations": {"$ref": "#/definitions/def_configurations"},
                "impact": {"$ref": "#/definitions/def_impact"},
                "publishedDate": {"type": "string"},
                "lastModifiedDate": {"type": "string"}
            },
            "required": ["cve"]
        }
```

I think the simplest (albeit not the most robust) would be to unmarshall into a `map[string]interface{}`

```golang
    type CVEItem struct {
        CVE              map[string]interface{} `json:"cve"`
        Configurations   map[string]interface{} `json:"configurations"`
        Impact           map[string]interface{} `json:"impact"`
        PublishedDate    string                 `json:"publishedDate"`
        LastModifiedDate string                 `json:"lastModifiedDate"`
    }

    type DataStruct struct {
        DataType string    `json:"CVE_data_type"`
        CVEItems []CVEItem `json:"CVE_items"`
    }

    var result DataStruct
    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(byteValue), &result)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
```

Then from this you can loop through the various items and build concrete structs from what is there (by looking at the keys). If there are many optional or nested items... then yes, it will be a pain to do.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Appreciate the link to the schema, not sure how I missed that, definitely useful. I think I am going to go the route of defining structs for everything in here since the JSON format should remain consistent. What's frustrating is some of the values are JSON objects that contain nothing except another JSON object, so its a lot of structs to create, but as long as I'm understanding things correctly I think this should work.

Comment: I still think it will be difficult if the JSON has a value of an array of one-of-many available types e.g. `key: obj1 | obj2 | obj....` then the closest general case is `key: interface{}`, It's hard to narrow that down to a struct. I saw that @volker posted the json-to-go link - I have used this in the past  and it works well for simpler stuff - I just ran the file through it and it has many repeated fields in the structs.